# SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) (View: /var/www/html/uberforx/app/views/website/index.blade.php)

Tags: php, database

I'm trying to install a script but I face this error when I try to access it over the browser:

```
SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using 
password: NO) (View: /var/www/html/uberforx/app/views/website/index.blade.php)
```

at http://104.236.150.121/uberforx/public/

Comment: try to provide IP address instead of localhost in host name.

Answer (score 1):

The script is configured to access a database and is currently configured to use root with no password.

Solution 1) Create the required database and structure for what you are using and set the username to root with no password.(Only accessibly through localhost).

Solution 2) Correct your environment configuration to make sure your database config is using root with the appropriate password.

Since you are using Laravel, it is most likely the environment config file that is the problem.

Comment: thanks, this helped me

Answer (score 0):

check your database config in dot env file

Comment: I think it is just a comment, not an answer! please use comment box for this type of info.